# Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "1"

Tags: firebase, react-native

How do I fix this error?

> Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "1". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.

I installed react-navigation, react-native-elements through npm when I believe the error occurred. So I uninstalled them and I still get the same error.

I also ran `yarn` and `npm install`

Here are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.2.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.0"
  }
```

[app.js and the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNAcy.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

hello you just need to put ctrl+c in your termial so you can stop the server
than  tap
npm start
or

yarn start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**You have some syntax error probably**

Attach snippets of `App.js` and the exact error stack trace you are getting with screenshots if possible.

Setup your node_modules from scratch again

Execute these:

```
1. rm -r node_modules

2. rm package-lock.json

3. expo upgrade

4. npm start -c
```

And install your dependencies once again either with npm or yarn.

**Note: Use any one (npm or yarn)**

Comment: There must be some error in node_modules, see the updated answer.